# uncaught reference $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, keyboard

I am trying to do a project with javascript using events on keys to display alphabets on the screen, I'm stuck with this error. please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

This is the script file that I'm using
```

**script.js**

```
(document).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    console.log("you pressed");
  }
});
```

Comment: You are missng jquery source included in your page, thus browser does not see $ character.

Comment: Did you by any chance forget a `$` in the 'script file' you posted here? Did you mean `$(document).keydown(function(event) {`?

Answer (score 1):

You're running your script before jQuery, so `$` doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

Place

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Before

```
<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```